# MySQL self join to flag duplicate rows - better way to do this?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that occasionally has duplicate row values, so I want to update anything except the first one and flag it as a duplicate.  Currently I'm using this but it can be very slow:

```
UPDATE _gtemp X
  JOIN _gtemp Y
  ON CONCAT(X.gt_spid, "-", X.gt_cov) = CONCAT(Y.gt_spid, "-", Y.gt_cov)
  AND Y.gt_dna = 0
  AND Y.gt_gtid < X.gt_gtid
  SET X.gt_dna = 1;
```

gt_spid is a numerical ID, and gt_cov is CHAR(3).  I have an index on gt_spid and a 2nd index on gt_spid, gt_cov.  At times this table can be upwards of 250,000 rows, but even at 30,000 it takes forever.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I can change the table as needed.

```
CREATE TABLE `_gtemp` (
  `gt_gtid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gt_group` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_spid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_cov` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_dna` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
 PRIMARY KEY (`gt_gtid`),
 KEY `spid` (`gt_spid`),
 KEY `spidcov` (`gt_spid`,`gt_cov`) USING HASH
 )
```

Comment: Instead of posting a pile of text describing your table and leaving out the important parts, you could just post the whole table definition.

Comment: why not set constraints on the appropriate columns in the table which would prevent duplicates from ever being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have used CONCAT makes MySQL optimizer lose it's indexes, resulting in very slow running query.

That's why you need to replace `CONCAT` with `AND` statements like below

```
UPDATE
     _gtemp X
  JOIN
    _gtemp Y
  ON
       X.gt_spid = Y.gt_spid
     AND
       X.gt_cov = Y.gt_cov
     AND
       Y.gt_dna = 0
     AND
       Y.gt_gtid < X.gt_gtid
  SET X.gt_dna = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll have to read up on CONCAT and indexes - I wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate `CONCAT` in `ON` clause and replace it with `AND` as follows.

Also have moved one restriction from `ON` to `WHERE` clause.

Add index to `gt_dna`

```
UPDATE _gtemp X
   JOIN _gtemp Y
   ON X.gt_spid = Y.gt_spid
   AND X.gt_cov = Y.gt_cov
   AND Y.gt_dna = 0
   SET X.gt_dna = 1
   WHERE Y.gt_gtid < X.gt_gtid
```